# Changing specific text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following html code , and I want to search the Welcome and make it bold .

```
<div class="welcome-msg">Welcome, First Name | </div>
```

the Output should be like this using DOM manipulation.

```
<div class="welcome-msg"><strong>Welcome</strong>, First Name | </div>
```

thanks ..

Comment: may we know why you want to do that, there may be better ways e.g. if you have control over html why not put welcome in a `span`

Answer (score 1):

```
var $welcomeMsg = $('.welcome.msg');
$welcomeMsg.html($welcomeMsg.text().replace(/(welcome)/i, '<strong>$1</strong>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need simple `replace` there:

```
var txt = $('div.welcome-msg').text();
$('div.welcome-msg').text(txt.replace('Welcome', '<strong>Welcome</strong>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could load the text as a variable but doing

```
var myvar=$('.welcome-msg').html();
```

to change the text

```
myvar=myvar.replace('Welcome', '<strong>Welcome</strong>');
```

then to put it back

```
$('.welcome-msg').html(myvar);
```

or in a single line

```
$('.welcome-msg').html($('.welcome-msg').html().replace('Welcome', '<strong>Welcome</strong>'));
```

Tested and work fine